# creating 200K relationships to a node is taking a lot of time in Neo4J 3.5?

Tags: neo4j

I have one vertex like this

**Vertex1**

```
{
    name:'hello',
    id: '2',
    key: '12345',
    col1: 'value1',
    col2: 'value2',
    .......
}
```

**Vertex2, Vertex3, ..... Vertex200K**

```
{
    name:'hello',
    id: '1',
    key: '12345',
    col1: 'value1',
    col2: 'value2',
    .......
}
```

**Cypher Query**

```
MATCH (a:Dense1) where a.id <> "1" 
WITH a 
MATCH (b:Dense1) where b.id = "1" 
WITH a,b 
WHERE a.key = b.key 
MERGE (a)-[:PARENT_OF]->(b)
```

The end result should be **Vertex1** should have **a degree of 200K**, therefore, there should be 200K relationships. However, the above query takes a lot of time pretty much killing the throughput to 500/second. Any ideas on how to create relationships/edges quicker?

When I run the profile and the cypher query above it keeps running forever and doesn't return so I reduced the size from 200K to 20K and here is what the profile is showing me.

[image]

Comment: Run the query with PROFILE and check/share what's happening?

Comment: Tried that also but it doesn't return it keeps running forever for the size mentioned above.

Comment: By changing the size to 1000 or 2000

Comment: done I reduced from 200K to 20K and attached the picture.

Comment: What's the `initial and maximum heap size` in neo4j conf?

Comment: In neo4j.conf I haven't set those so whatever the default is. I just checked the neo4j.conf file and initial and max heap size are commented out.

Comment: Can you uncomment and set the `maximum value` to half of your RAM size?

Comment: Don't forget to restart neo4j after changes

Comment: okies. I set `dbms.memory.heap.max_size=16G` and I restarted. I can see the neo4j process started -Xmx 16G. I will rerun the query and let you know.

Comment: From the result of `PROFILE`, it looks like your query is not using `INDEX`. Can you check once again you have created the index on `id` and `key` property of `Dense1`? It's case sensative.

Comment: Thanks, I need a few hours to re-run and paste the results here. please keep an eye on this thread. Thanks much.

Comment: just for learning purposes What is the default heap size anyways? and why set it to half?

Comment: Don't remember the Default value. It's set to half so that other programs get some memory otherwise we will not be able to run other programs

Comment: There is no other program running in this machine other than neo4j so neo4j can use all the 32GB available I don't mind.

Comment: Okay, You can read more about how to decide configurations here: https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/how-to-estimate-initial-memory-configuration/

Comment: Attached the screen shots. yeah I don't think it is using indexes. EXPAND(INTO) seems to be taking the most amount of time. Not sure how to fix it?

Comment: The profile plan DOES show it's using indexes (see the two NodeIndeSeeks), so indexing is not the issue here. Could you expand all elements of your plan (the double-down arrow in the lower left corner of the result pane) and add that to your question (replacing the unexpanded version)? That will give context as to what parts of the query are associated with which parts of the plan.

Comment: @InverseFalcon just did as you requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your memory constraints, and the high db hits associated with your MERGE of the relationships, the issue is likely that you're trying to MERGE 200k relationships in a single transaction. You should probably batch this by using [apoc.periodic.iterate()](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#commit-batching) from [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/):

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate("
MATCH (a:Dense1) 
WHERE a.id <> '1'
MATCH (b:Dense1) 
WHERE b.id = '1' AND a.key = b.key 
RETURN a, b",
"MERGE (a)-[:PARENT_OF]->(b)",
{}) YIELD batches, total, errorMessages
RETURN batches, total, errorMessages
```

This should batch those merges 10k at a time.

Also, if you happen to know for a fact that those relationships don't yet exist, use CREATE instead of MERGE, it will be faster.

Comment: Yes you are correct I am trying to merge 200K relationships in one transaction. But I also tried batching using `UNWIND` which yielded better performance like 1000/sec which is still slow (when I benchmarked last time). currently, it is 500/sec. what is the difference between batching using `UNWIND` and `apoc.periodic.iterate` ?

Comment: Also, I am not sure why this is an expensive operation? if I do this postgres it will join all 200K in less than a second since the total number of relationships is only 200K so in postgres case it will be 200K rows. I understand Postgres or any DBMS for that matter is not a good fit to join in depth first manner. But I fail to understand why we cannot have both for Graph database like Neo4j? why not have an extra data structure on disk for nodes with a high degree?

Comment: UNWIND doesn't do batching. It's the opposite of a `collect()`, producing a row per list element. When I'm talking about batching, I'm talking about dividing your writes into separate transactions. Since transactions must be atomic, all changes for a single transaction must manifest in the heap. If you're trying to write too much at once, you may run out of heap, and if you don't blow your heap you may end up with too little to do anything meaningful and the garbage collector churns without progress. This approach will at the least rule out this issue, if problems remain we can troubleshoot.

Comment: This is not batching? ```UNWIND {batch} as row
MERGE (n:Label {row.id})
(ON CREATE) SET n += row.properties```

Comment: It's not so much that we're looking at only 200k rows, because we're not. Your MERGE of the relationship must check to see if the relationship already exists between the two nodes, so it has to expand from one side or the other, and see, among all the connected nodes, if it is connected to the other one by that relationship. And if it isn't then it has to take locks and check again (double-checked locking because the relationship could have been added between the time it checked before, and the time it took locks), and then the relationships are written if needed.

Comment: No, that's not batching (unless the query is being called per batch...we'd really need to see that full query to make that determination). UNWIND by itself doesn't imply batching. It's just the opposite of a collect().

Comment: the `batch` here is a batch of messages from Kafka. so that batch would contain say 10K messages. so yeah I am calling UNWIND after my kafka consumer consumes a batch from the broker.

Comment: Let me change merge to create and see how it performs. It will take me no time.

Comment: As long as that snippet with UNWIND is the full query, then yes that could be a batch. Just keep in mind that although the UNWIND allows you to take a list of input and transform it into some number of rows so you can execute it all at once, what causes it to actually batch is that the queries are being called separately, so each call happens in its own transaction. So UNWIND is a component of dealing with a batch (send in a list of things to process, UNWIND them, process them), but the separate transaction per query call is what keeps the heap from blowing up when processing big input.

Comment: Let me try something based on your suggestions. will share the findings!

Comment: I ran your code. It gives me a syntax exception with no useful error messages. not sure how to fix it?

Comment: `Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed: Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.periodic.iterate`: Caused by: org.neo4j.cypher.internal.v3_5.util.SyntaxException: Invalid input 'H': expected 'i/I' (line 1, column 94 (offset: 93))`

Comment: My fault there, I'm used to each clause being on its own line, so missed the `where` on the line before mine, Two WHERE clauses can't be used back to back. Fixed the query.

Comment: Thanks that helps. with `apoc.periodic.iterate` Merge takes about 12 seconds and without `apoc.periodic.iterate` Merge takes about 35 seconds. I changed it to CREATE as you suggested and used the UNWIND operation as discussed above it took about one second to create a node with fan out of 200K relationships!

Comment: One thing I notice with all these experiments is that while doing batching the time to finish the batch is monotonically increasing as the relationships are getting constructed. Tells me Writes have to be spread out across nodes. otherwise not sure how to scale it for billions of relationships?

Comment: While `CREATE` is a lot faster how can I make sure the `CREATE` throws an Exception if a relationship already exists when run multiple times?

Comment: Currently you can't. If you can't guarantee the relationship exists, or that your query won't produce duplicate relationships between the same nodes, then for correct behavior you'll need to use MERGE for this, unfortunately. Relationship writes can end up being a bit slow...locks need to be taken, double-checks need to be done after locking, and writes happen on both nodes to include the relationship. That's the setup needed for faster reads, as we don't need to use joins when traversing, just jumping pointers.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for that explanation. `MERGE` takes a huge performance hit though. `CREATE UNIQUE` seems to be faster than `MERGE` although not sure why it is getting deprecated! Moreover, I am pretty sure there must be ways to make MERGE Faster. I am thinking if I should create an issue on github? if this is all about reads why not something like snapshot isolation?

Comment: CREATE UNIQUE has some issues, among them I don't think it does double-checked locking, so I believe it's vulnerable to race conditions. Also it doesn't offer the flexibility (coming at a cost of a steeper learning curve) that MERGE does. It simply cannot address some of the use cases that MERGE can.

Answer (score 0):

**Create an Index on the properties you are using for matching.**

Here `id` and `key` properties.

You can create an index with the following queries:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Schema1(id);
CREATE INDEX ON :Schema1(key);
```

*This is the first step to improve performance.
You can further improve with a few other tricks.*

Answer (score 0):

Can you try running

```
MATCH (b:Dense1) where b.id <> "1" 
WITH b, b.key AS bKey
MATCH (a:Dense1) where a.id = "1" AND a.key = bKey 
MERGE (a)-[:PARENT_OF]->(b)
```

after ensuring you have indexes on id and key ?

Also, do I get this right that id is NOT unique, and you have 1 node with id=2 and 200k with id = 1? If I got this wrong flip the condition to make the first line return single node, one you want to have all relations coming into, and second part matching all the remaining 200k nodes. Also, in the merge, put the low-density node as the first one (so here, b would get 200k relationships in) - if that's not right, reverse it to be (b) <-[:XXX]-(a).

It's been a while since I was dealing with large imports/merges, but I recall that extracting the variable explicitly (e.g. bKey) that can then be matched in index, and starting from single nodes (single, or just a few b's) moving onto higher (multiple a's) was working better than queries with where clauses similar to a.key = b.key.

Having said that, 200k relationships in one transaction, AND connected to single node, is a lot, since just matching on the index finds the nodes quickly, but still you need to validate all outgoing relationships to see if by chance they already link to the other node. So, by the time you create your last relationship, you need to iterate/check nearly 200k relationships.

One trick is running batches in a loop until nothing gets created, e.g.

```
MATCH (b:Dense1) where b.id = "1" 
WITH b, b.key AS bKey
MATCH (a:Dense1) where a.id <> "1" AND a.key = bKey 
AND NOT (a) -[:PARENT_OF]-> (b) WITH a,b LIMIT 10000
MERGE (a)-[:PARENT_OF]->(b)
```

This might show you probably that the further the batch, the longer it takes - makes sense logically, as more and more relationships out of b need to be checked the further you go.

Or, as shown in other responses, batch via APOC.

Last thing - is this supposed to be ongoing process or one-time setup / initialisation of the DB? There are more, dramatically faster options if it's for initial load only.