# How to prevent duplicate relationships without using MERGE Neo4J 3.5?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How to prevent duplicate relationships without using MERGE Neo4J 3.5?

I want to run the following Query for every batch I get from Kafka.

```
MATCH (a:Dense1) where a.id <> "1" 
WITH a 
MATCH (b:Dense1) where b.id = "1" 
WITH a,b 
WHERE a.key = b.key 
CREATE (a)-[:PARENT_OF]->(b)
```

If I change `CREATE` to `MERGE` performance slows down significantly because of double locking as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56884135/creating-200k-relationships-to-a-node-is-taking-a-lot-of-time-in-neo4j-3-5?noredirect=1#comment100319365_56884135) if I change CREATE to `CREATE UNIQUE` Performance is better than `MERGE` but still not Good as `CREATE`alone. My goal is if a relationship exists between two nodes just don't do anything even if the query is run multiple times or even better send a notification or exception to the client driver so the application can do something useful. Can I create a `uid` property for every relationship and have a constraint on it? would that work?

Answer (score 0):

You can add in your latest `WHERE` clause a check if the relationship is there or not :

```
MATCH (a:Dense1) where a.id <> "1" 
WITH a 
MATCH (b:Dense1) where b.id = "1" 
WITH a,b 
WHERE a.key = b.key AND NOT (a)-[:PARENT_OF]->(b)
CREATE (a)-[:PARENT_OF]->(b)
```

But this is pretty much what the `MERGE` command is doing ...

Do you have an index/constraint on the properties `id` and `key` ?

Comment: No index or constraint

Comment: Ok, so your performance issue comes from that. You should create an index on the property `key` : `CREATE INDEX ON :Dense1(key)`

Comment: Created index still very slow just to create 200K relationships for one node and that is my entire graph so the total number of edges is also 200K.

Comment: Keep in mind that the solution here is not safe from race conditions. If you are certain that no other query is executing that will be creating these same relationships, then you should be fine. Otherwise (such as if this query was run concurrently with itself) you might end up with duplicate relationships between the same nodes.

Comment: What do you mean by slow ? Can you give the execution time ? Can you also provide the explain of the query ?